# Encrypt larger string to smaller string using C# like reverse md5

Tags: c#, string, encryption, md5

We are trying to convert text "HELLOWORLDTHISISALARGESTRINGCONTENT" into a smaller text. while doing it using MD5 hash we are getting the 16 byte, since it is a one way encryption we are not able to decrypt it. Is there any other way to convert this large string to smaller and revert back the same data? If so please let us know how to do it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you just looking to compress the string, or encrypt it?

Comment: I do want to compress a string in the above case, if my input contains 75 characters I do want to get 25 character string. It is like compressing a string

Comment: the sample contains `Capital A-Z` `0-9` is this correct? if correct then can the output string contain a mix of uppercase/lowercase plus some special chars like those over the numbers !@#$%^&*(){}+= ? if you allow doing so then we *can* actually compress it a bit. how much we can compress remains to be calculated.

Comment: are you trying to create a CD-KEY / Product-Key sort of thing having embedded licensing information?

Comment: I am not trying to create CD-KEY / Product-Key, but trying to embed data in the strings

Answer (score 2):

Most compression algorithms won't be able to do much with a sequence that short (or may actually make it bigger) - so no: there isn't much you can do to magically shrink it. Your best bet would probably be just generate a guid, and store the *full* value keyed against the guid (in a database or whatever), and then use the short value as a one-time usage key, to look up the long value (and then erase the record).

Answer (score 0):

It heavily depends on the input data. In general - the worst case - you can't lessen the size of a string through compression if the input data is not long enough and has a high entropy.

Hashing is the wrong approach as a hashing function tries to map a large input data to a short one, but it does not guarantee (by itself) that you can't find a second set of data to map to the same string.

What you can try to do is to imlement a compression algorithm or a lookback table.
Compression can be done by ziplib or any other compression library (just google for it). The lookback approach requires a second place to store the lookup information. For example, when you get the first input string, you map it to the number 1 and save the information 1 maps to {input data} somewhere else. For every subsequent data set you add another mapping entry. If the input data set is finite, this approach may save you space.

Comment: I tried compressing a string, the string length is greater than the input

Comment: @Venkatraman that is the overhead of storing the compression header information. Your input string is too short to use compression.

Comment: In this case what Do I do to achieve it. I do want to convert it 25 characters from a 75 character string (vice versa)

Comment: @Venkatraman in that case, follow my second advice (lookup table).